# How to Restrict Read and Write to specific Firebase Node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have below Firebase Database Structure. I am not authenticating user with firebase.Using Mysql for user Authentication.I want to secure my entire Firebase database allowing reading and writing to `Driver` `books` and `pos` node only. user or someone can not create new node or download database and only can read and write if he knows the specified node name only.

[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```
{
"rules": {


  "Driver_xgfururi": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true
  },

  "books_xgfururi": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true
  },


  "pos_xgfururi": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true
  },

  "req_xgfururi": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true
  }

 }
}
```

is it possible for any hacker findout above node if it is not shared ? and can someone read-write without knowing above node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is usually accessed directly from the client-side application. In that case it can only be secured with [Firebase's server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security). And the only knowledge in those rules about the user of the application, is if that use is signed in with Firebase Authentication.

If you have another sign-in mechanism already, you will have to pass that information securely to Firebase Authentication, which will then in turn pass it into the security rules for database calls. You can do this by [minting a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) based on the authentication result you have (on your server), and then passing that token to the client, which can use it to [sign in to Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients).

Comment: if I save data under a child name like `mydata_cpT5xroK1u9zik` and set rules read and write for this node only then is it possible for someone read and write data without knowing this node ? and is it possible for someone to findout this node?

Comment: It **is** possible to make things quite secure by using obscure node names. But that depends on your security rules, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the security rules I have added.Pls suggest

Comment: In the rules you showed, a user can only read/write the specified nodes if they know their URL. I've used this approach repeatedly myself, although with longer, and unique, random character sequences.

Comment: is it good enough to secure the database and is it possible for any user or hacker findout this node if it is not shared